# How to reuse pattern by adding variables in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to reuse multi patterns by simply changing index (for example, L1,L2 ...) in patterns instead of creating multiple patterns but I don't know how to replace the variable in the patterns with "i". my program is to check three patterns in each lines and if there's any string matched to one of three patterns then increase the count.
I started with below but can't finished. can anyone know how to make this work?
thanks,

```
 patterns = ['Test\(L{0}\)ABCDE'.format,
             'Test\(L{0}\)EFIGH'.format,
             'Test\(L{0}\)IJKLM'.format,
             ]
 for i in range(1,20):
     output_format = "|".join(pattern)        
     count = sum(1 for line in myfile if re.search(output_format, %i, line))
```

Comment: Please show us where you actually _use_ the `patterns` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want strings in the list of patterns, not references to their `format` methods, and then you want to call the format method on each of those strings, passing the iteration variable to that method. Code not tested:

```
patterns = ['Test\(L{0}\)ABCDE',
           'Test\(L{0}\)EFIGH',
           'Test\(L{0}\)IJKLM',
           ]
for i in range(1,20):
    expression = "|".join(pattern.format(i) for pattern in patterns)        
    count = sum(1 for line in myfile if re.search(expression, line))
```